# MySQL multiple "AND" statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query with multiple WHERE clauses. If I do a multiple search, it returns a record from a single criteria. I need this query to return a result that has ALL of the criteria instead of just one.

You can see it [here](http://www.menuhead.net/Steelers/2Expert.php).

Additionally, I have provided the code:

```
if (isset ( $_POST ["btnSearch"] )) {
echo "<br>Selected Options are :<br>";
$checked = $_POST ["criteria"];

$criteria = "";
$separator = ", ";
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $checked ); $i ++) {
    echo "  " . $checked [$i] . "<br/>";

    if ($i == count ( $checked ) - 1) {
        $separator = "";
    }

    $criteria = $criteria . "'" . $checked [$i] . "'" . $separator;
}
echo "<br><br>";

echo $criteria . "<br><br>";
include "config.php";

mysql_select_db ( "MyHead", $con );
//$DM = implode(',',$criteria);
$mysqlQuery = "SELECT tblRestaurants.RestName, tblLocDet.LocationID, tblLocDet.DetailID, tblDetails.DetailName, tblRestaurants.RestName
FROM tblRestaurants INNER JOIN (tblLocations INNER JOIN (tblLocDet INNER JOIN tblDetails ON  tblLocDet.DetailID = tblDetails.DetailID) ON tblLocations.LocationID = tblLocDet.LocationID) ON  tblRestaurants.RestID = tblLocations.RestID
GROUP BY tblRestaurants.RestName, tblLocDet.LocationID, tblLocDet.DetailID, tblDetails.DetailName
 HAVING tblDetails.DetailName IN (" . $criteria . ");";

if (! $rs = mysql_query ( $mysqlQuery )) {
    echo "Cannot parse query";
} elseif (mysql_num_rows ( $rs ) == 0) {
    echo "No records found";
} else {
    echo "<table id=\"myTable\" table width=\"710\" class=\"beautifuldata\" align=\"Left\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
    echo "<th>PLACE</th>";
    echo "<th>ADDRESS</th>";
    echo "<th>PHONE</th>";
    echo "<th>PRICE</th>";
    echo "<th>RATING</th>";
    echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $rs ) ) {
        echo "<tr><td><strong><a href='" . $row [RestPage] . "'>" . $row ['RestName'] . "</a></strong></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['DetailName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['Phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['Price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row ['Rating'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table><br />\n";

mysql_close ( $con );
}
?>
```

Tables:

```
tblRestaurants (RestID, RestName)
tblLocations (LocationID, CityID, AreaID, CuisineID)
tblLocDet (DetailID, LocationID)
tblDetails (DetailID, DetailName, DetailType)
```

Comment: Why so much code? Just limit the question to the SQL query in question along with the structure of the tables.

Comment: Better!  Just wanted everyone to see everything!

Comment: So you are looking for those rows that had all the items in the criteria in the predicate `IN` at the same time?

Comment: Having the tables structure would be handy.

Comment: Look Up!  Added them at the end of the Code.

Comment: Yes, I need the result to have ALL of the criteria.

Comment: Obligatory: [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) and don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Does the table `tblRestaurants ` have a location field?

Comment: oops!  Add a RestID field to the tblLocations.  Sorry.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that all the selected rows have all the items in the `$criteria`, one way to do so is to count those items in this criteria variable and then having a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DetailName) = $n`, so that any selected rows should have all of them, something like:

```
SELECT 
  r.RestName, 
  ld.LocationID, 
  ld.DetailID, 
  d.DetailName
FROM tblRestaurants     AS r
INNER JOIN tblLocations AS l  ON r.RestID     = l.RestID
INNER JOIN tblLocDet    AS ld ON l.LocationID = ld.LocationID
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT l.Locationid
  FROM tblLocDet l
  INNER JOIN tbldetails d ON l.detailid = d.detailid
  WHERE d.detailname IN ('det1', 'det2', 'det3')
  GROUP BY l.locationid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DetailName) = $n
)                       AS ld2 ON ld.locationid = ld2.locationid
INNER JOIN tblDetails   AS d   ON ld.DetailID   = d.DetailID   
GROUP BY r.RestName, 
         ld.LocationID, 
         ld.DetailID, 
         d.DetailName;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fe92/7).

This will give you something like:

```
| RESTNAME | LOCATIONID | DETAILID | DETAILNAME |
-------------------------------------------------
|     res1 |          1 |        1 |       det1 |
|     res1 |          1 |        2 |       det2 |
|     res1 |          1 |        3 |       det3 |
```

---

You can, however, shorten this query; for example if you remove the `detailid`, and `detailname` from the `GROUP BY` clause and use the `GROUP_CONCAT` to select them in one row concatenated with `,` like this:

```
SELECT 
  r.RestName, 
  ld.LocationID, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.DetailName separator ',') Details
FROM tblRestaurants     AS r
INNER JOIN tblLocations AS l  ON r.RestID     = l.RestID
INNER JOIN tblLocDet    AS ld ON l.LocationID = ld.LocationId
INNER JOIN tblDetails   AS d  ON ld.DetailID  = d.DetailID   
WHERE d.detailname IN ('det1', 'det2', 'det3')
GROUP BY r.RestName, 
         ld.LocationID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.DetailName) = 3;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fe92/6).

This will give you something like:

```
| RESTNAME | LOCATIONID |        DETAILS |
------------------------------------------
|     res1 |          1 | det3,det2,det1 |
```

**Note that:**  the `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.DetailName) = 3` will give you all the rows that have all the details names = 3 if you want to get those rows that had *at least* change it to `>=`.

Comment: This appears to work in Fiddle.  Just a question.  A little confused about the Create table thing.  Is this a temp table that will be created everytime a query is made and then destroyed?  Quite an incredible answer!

Comment: OK, Over my head for now.  What exactly does this mean.  I've not seen this before.  Thank you foryour patience.    r.RestName, 
  ld.LocationID, 
  ld.DetailID, 
  d.DetailName

Comment: @ME-dia - I don't know really how SQLFiddle work, but you will always find your table and query in this link whenever you browse this url, what I have done in this query is what is called [***Relation Division***](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), so does it work fine for you?

Comment: Yes so far.  Thank you.  I will read the article. Can this be translated into regular MySQL?

Comment: @ME-dia - I think this article was not intended for specific RDBMS, all the SQL things should work in all RDMS in the same way with some tiny variations, the same with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need this query:

```
SELECT tblRestaurants.RestName, ...
FROM tblRestaurants 
INNER JOIN tblLocations ON tblLocations.RestID = tblRestaurants.RESTID
INNER JOIN tblLocDet ON tblLocDet.LocationID = tblLocations.LocationID
INNER JOIN tblDetails ON tblLocDet.DetailID  = tblDetails.DetailID
WHERE tblDetails.DetailName IN (" . $criteria . ");";
ORDER BY...
```

You do not need `GROUP BY` as you have no aggregate functions (MIN, MAX etc). Use `ORDER BY` to sort the list.

Also a good idea to move to mysqli_* (or PDO) functions and use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Thank you. Go to this link...http://www.menuhead.net/Steelers/3Expert.php      Select Fireplace and Private rooms, there should be three places, I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Oops - Got a bit distracted figuring out your tables. Will have a think about the "ALL criteria" bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ["btnSearch"] )) {
$checked = (array) $_POST ["criteria"];
sort($checked);
$criteria = implode(",", $checked);
echo "<br>Selected Options are :<br>" . $criteria . "<br><br>";

include "config.php";

mysql_select_db ( "MyHead", $con );

$criteria = mysql_real_escape_string($criteria);

$mysqlQuery = "
SELECT r.RestName, ld.LocationID, ld.DetailID, d.DetailName, r.RestName
FROM tblRestaurants AS r
INNER JOIN tblLocations AS l 
  ON r.RestID = l.RestID
INNER JOIN tblLocDet AS ld 
  ON l.LocationID = ld.LocationID 
INNER JOIN tblDetails AS d 
  ON ld.DetailID = d.DetailID
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DetailID, GROUP_CONCAT(DetailName ORDER BY DetailName) AS DetailList 
  FROM tblDetails GROUP BY DetailID) AS dx
  ON ld.DetailID = dx.DetailID
WHERE dx.DetailList = '$criteria'";

if (! $rs = mysql_query ( $mysqlQuery )) {
  . . .
```

The rest would be the same as your code.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried it but unless I select only one option, it returns no records found.